# Formatting output of 2 minute countdown timer

Tags: javascript

I want to make just a standard 2 minute countdown to go with a quote on a site "Every two minutes a child enters the system in the US" I have this code, and I want to make the output bigger, bold, and a different font.  What and where do I add this info? Sorry I know this is such a basic question but would appreciate the help!

```
<div id=timer></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeoutHandle;
function countdown(minutes, seconds) {
    function tick() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
        counter.innerHTML =
            minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
        seconds--;
        if (seconds >= 0) {
            timeoutHandle = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        } else {
            if (minutes >= 1) {
                // countdown(mins-1);   never reach “00″ issue solved:Contributed by Victor Streithorst
                setTimeout(function () {
                    countdown(minutes - 1, 59);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
    tick();
}

countdown(2, 00);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the div from the timer a class-name and than add the styling in your CSS.

```js
var timeoutHandle;
function countdown(minutes, seconds) {
    function tick() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
        counter.innerHTML =
            minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
        seconds--;
        if (seconds >= 0) {
            timeoutHandle = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        } else {
            if (minutes >= 1) {
                // countdown(mins-1);   never reach “00″ issue solved:Contributed by Victor Streithorst
                setTimeout(function () {
                    countdown(minutes - 1, 59);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
    tick();
}

countdown(2, 00);
```

```css
.timer {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div timer id='timer' class=timer></div>
```

You can include the css-file with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>` into your HTML-file.

**Alternative:** You could use inline CSS:

```
<div timer id='timer' style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px; font-style: italic;"></div>
```

But this solution is **not recommended**. It's good style to separate HTML, CSS and JavaScript in different files.

Comment: You should avoid styling with ID, use classes instead

Comment: You are right. I just uses the id because the OP is a newbie and for this I left it as easy as possible. I changed it to using a class.